# Re-sizing website widgets width & height CSS

Tags: html, css, widget

How can i change the width and height of each individual widget i've add to the bottom of my footer. http://jjabaird.virb.com/

For example, i have 3 widgets and each widget is set at 320px, i would like one of those three widgets to be 960px and another a different size.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you explain more the current problem?

Comment: @BkSantiago I can't figure out how to adjust the width and height of each widget. For example the "mm" titled widget i have, i'm looking to adjust the width of the widget.

Comment: you got three answers in record time for a simple question.. please choose one so that people feel motivated to spend the time to answer your future questions

Comment: Lol, @abbood, i'm testing to see which one will work best. I always vote up on an answer, but had you seen that, you wouldn't be making the comment above.

Comment: i apologize jbnbtw.. i figured as much.. that's why i worded my comment as politely as possible.. in that case.. i owe you another answer.. only this time don't feel obliged to vote ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code

```
<div class="wrapper">            
        <article class="widget rss">
        </article>
        <article class="widget blank">
            <h2>Bleh</h2>
            <p>Testing Testing Testing</p>
        </article>
        <article class="widget blank">
            <h2>Bleh 2</h2>
            <p>testing testing testing</p>
        </article>            
    </div>
```

and css:

```
.wrapper { 
    max-width: 960px; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0 auto;
 }

.widgets article.widget { 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
     width: 31.3%; 
    float: left; 
}
```

the containing div `wrapper` has a max width of 960px.. at the same time each widget it contains has a width of 31%.. so if you change the width of the first widget to 320px.. then the other two will bump down.. (b/c they are all set to `float: left`).. so what you want to do is increase the size of the first to 320px, but also adjust the sizes of the other two so that they are small enough to be contained within the wrapper div

ie the total of widths must be <= 960px.. (and you have to also take into account the widget's margins and paddings when you do your calculation)

but if you just change the width of the first widget to 320px and leave the other two.. you'll end up with
 (320px + .31(960) + .31(960)) > 960

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @abbood works perfectly! And i appreciate the clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you didn't do that website? In what i see, the width of the widget is 31.3%, and the three widgets Plus their margins make it 100%..

if you want to change it, you can override in css it by adding `width: 320px !important;`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.widgets article.widget {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 310px;
}
```

three  widgets  `310*3=930` and `margin-right:15px;` `15*2=30` so `930+30= 960`.

and third widgets give float:right;

```
<article class="widget blank" style="float: right;">
                <h2>Bleh 2</h2>
                <p>testing testing testing</p>

            </article>
```